Have any countries considered allowing supersonic flights overland?
The Concorde (partially) failed due to the lack of overland flying permissions, which in turn was due to the loud boom experienced by ground observers. But (in theory) it would be perfectly safe to allow such flights at the cost of some discomfort for local residents who would periodically hear loud booms in their neighborhood.
Have any countries (say, the Soviet Union?) considered ignoring the concerns of ground observers and allowing such flights overground, at least for certain limited routes avoiding major cities? This might be tricky in Western Europe but would otherwise be feasible in less dense parts of the world.

Related: Why was there no issue with the Tu-144 flying above land?

In the Sixtes, sonic booms were not that infrequent in Europe. NATO airplanes exercising over West Germany regularly broke the sound barrier. East European air forces trained less but took even less care of avoiding sonic booms.

I can confirm. For half of the eighties, we lived ~100 km from Ramstein and ~30 km from Frankfurt, for the other half, we lived ~75 km from both. I believe there was also a MOZ for training not far. Sonic booms were completely normal – after all, it is hard to train far away from population if the entire country is just 20 minutes "wide" for a jet fighter at top speed.

In the US, there are low and high-altitude supersonic testing corridors in southern California. People in northern LA county and southern Kern county and adjacent areas are accustomed to occasional sonic booms. Also, White Sands in New Mexico and now an area of Kansas have supersonic test airspace as well. When an airplane was hijacked in Washington, some Oregon NG Eagles boomed the Pacific northwest enroute to intercept. When the Chinese balloon was shot down, there were booms. I'm guessing the intent of the question is for purposes of regular commercial operation.

Also, when the Space Shuttle landed and when the SpaceX boosters return, there were/are significant overpressure spikes. The X-59  is preparing to test supersonically over land, including over communities not normally exposed to booms to gather data on human perceptions to a shaped and reduced boom signature.

As a side note (pun intended), it's important to point out that significant noise events can occur over land from aircraft operating supersonically over the ocean. Two examples are F-22 flight testing miles off shore in the Pacific that occasionally startled coastal residents and reports of mysterious sounds in the northeastern US possibly from the secondary carpet of the Concorde far offshore (c.f. Acoustics Today magazine, Spring 2015, volume 11, issue 2.

@mins https://boomsupersonic.com/ is trying to bring back supersonic flights, just like Elon unilaterally brought back rocket launch capability to the US.
